# Opentok on ionic react capacitor

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, opentok, capacitor

I tried using opentok on ionic react app using capacitor, it works ok with android but on ios, it says OT_NOT_SUPPORTED. Does anyone already tried implementing opentok on ionic react capacitor app? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic apps are not pure native app, they use webview to render your web application, so for using opentok with ionic you don’t need to install any native plugins . These are the steps you need to do. 1. Go to IOS Info.plist and add these permissions

```html
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key> 
<string>Your message to user when the camera is accessed for the first time</string> 
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key> 
<string>Your message to user when the microphone is accessed for the first time</string>
```

2. Go to Androidmanifest.xml and add theses permissions

```html
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

3. Now use opentok client in your code how you do for any web application  it will work fine.
   https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/web/basic-video-chat/